# Laravel - How to validate either email of phone as required

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-8, I am using Rules Request and I have this code:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'phone_number' => [
            'required',
            'numeric',
    Rule::unique('companies', 'email')
        ],
        'email' => [
            'required',
            'email',
            'max:80',
            Rule::unique('companies', 'email')
        ],
    ];
}
```

How do I validate either phone or email as required and not both?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [required_without](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-without):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        "phone_number" => "required_without:email",
        "email" => "required_without:phone_number"
    ];
}
```